# Accessing Nodes from external XML with document() XSLT

Tags: xslt, svg, saxon

I'm trying to iterate through a directory of SVGs to access some metadata within. I can iterate fine, however, when I attempt to get the value of a specific node within each I seem to fail.

Using SaxonHE 9.4 (Java) to transform.

The example here seems straightforward enough:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('geneva.xml')/ph:photo/ph:title"/>
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/

Yet I have my XSLT (the relevant portion; no iteration atm just a test to get external node value):

```
<div>
<p><xsl:value-of select="document('images/test.svg')"/></p>
</div>
```

But all this gives me is:

```
<div><p>Mine
circle:hover {fill-opacity:0.9;}
</p></div>
```

I've tried `document('images/test.svg')/svg/title` but that gives me nothing in return

*test.svg*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>Mine</title>
<style type="text/css">
circle:hover {fill-opacity:0.9;}
</style>
<g style="fill-opacity:0.7;">
<circle cx="6.5cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1cm" transform="translate(0,50)" />
<circle cx="6.5cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:blue; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1cm" transform="translate(70,150)" />
<circle cx="6.5cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:green; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1cm" transform="translate(-70,150)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG elements are bound to the SVG namespace. It was set without a namespace prefix:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

So, you need to declare that namespace in your XSLT with a namespace-prefix, and use that namespace-prefix to address the SVG elements in your XPath:

```
document('images/test.svg')/svg:svg/svg:title
```

Comment: Beautiful `<xsl:value-of xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" select="document('images/test.svg')/svg:svg/svg:title"/>` Always the namespacing giving me issues. Thanks!